# How to get property in code behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on ASP.NET. I am new to it. I need to set a table property `(iscollect="true")`. I need to get this property in my code behind. How to get it as true. Please help. Thanks in advance

or if i am doing anything wrong plz suggest me 
here is my example goes

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" runat="server" id="Personal" iscollect="true">
    <tr>
        <td><btn:collection ID="collect" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code behind

```
public bool iscollect { get; set; }
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool var = iscollect;
    if (iscollect==true)
    {
        Personalcollect.Visible = true;
        SavecollectDetails();
    }
}
```

How to get this property as true as i set in code behind. Please help. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how did you manage to compile your code, but this should work:

```
public bool iscollect {
    get {return (bool)(ViewState["iscollect"] ?? false)}
    set { ViewState["iscollect"] = value; }
}

protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    iscollect = Convert.ToBoolean(Personal.Attributes["iscollect"]);

    if (iscollect)
    {
        Personalcollect.Visible = true;
        SavecollectDetails();
    }
}


<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" runat="server" id="Personal" iscollect="<%=iscollect%>">
    <tr><td><btn:collection ID="collect" runat="server" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thnks for reply MelanciaUK but the Attribute not supporting

Comment: I've misspelled it before. It's `Attributes`.

Comment: thanks for reply MelanciaUK thnks very much it's working but i need to acces it to in anoteher page like i am redirectiong controller to SavecollectDetails(); this method it is in another page there can get my propety iscollect as true using by above code

Comment: I've merged my answer with the one given by @A. Tapper.

Answer (score 1):

The iscollect wont be persisted between requests. Try storing it in the viewstate like this:

```
public bool iscollect {
    get {return (bool)(ViewState["iscollect"] ?? false)}
    set { ViewState["iscollect"] = value; }
}
```

And then add the attribute in the ASPX file:

```
iscollect="<%= iscollect %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attributes of table using `Attributes` property like this

```
string value = Personal.Attributes["iscollect"].ToString();
```

As you have declare a Property named `iscollect` on the page, you can assign it to the value specified in the table markup.

```
private bool _isCollect = false;
public bool IsCollect
{
  get
  {
    Boolean.TryParse(Personal.Attributes["iscollect"], out _isCollect);
    return _isCollect;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

In ASPX:

```
... runat="server" id="Personal"iscollect='<%=iscollect%>'>
```

Comment: thnks for replying Samiey Mehdi